# Clicking A tag in IE6 and FF using jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-6, onclick, microsoft-ajax

I have a `div` that is returned from an ajax call which contains an `a`. I need to click it in javascript, however I cannot find a way that works in both IE6 and FF.

This works in FF but generates an *object required* error in IE6:

```
$('#mylink').click();
```

This works in IE6 but generates a *$("#mylink").get(0).click is not a function* error in FF.

```
$('#mylink').get(0).click();
```

Any ideas on why this is and what kind of solution is available?

EDIT:

Using trigger returns the same error as click in IE6:

```
$('#mylink').trigger('click');
```

EDIT:

Placing the code in a timer does not change the behavior:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
  $('#mylink').click();
 }, 100);
```

EDIT:

As a workaround, this functions. But it would be nice to better understand the issue. This is not a jQuery issue alone (or maybe at all). The IE6 JavaScript error comes out of MicrosoftAjax.js so it has something to do with that.

```
 var anchor = $('#mylink');
 if (anchor.get(0).click) {
  anchor.get(0).click();
 }
 else {
  anchor.click();
 }
```

Comment: Can we see some code? If the click() method fails it's most likely because it's been called before the dynamic DIV is actually inserted.

Comment: The MS Ajax OnSuccess event calls a method which executes the above code. I have tried placing the code in a setTimeout thinking that it needed time to complete the insertion, but no joy. I would have to create a simplified implementation to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $("#mylink").click() isn't found but $("#mylink").get(0).click() is, then could you use this as the basis for a test?

eg

```
if ($("#mylink").click)
{
    $("#mylink").click()
}
elseif ($("#mylink").get(0))
{
    $("#mylink").get(0).click();
}
```

Far from ideal I know but such is the way of things when dealing with IE6

Comment: +1 Because jQuery returns a valid jQuery object which has a click the test needs to be the other way around. I'll update the question with this info.

Answer (score 1):

The get method returns the DOM element.
You shoudl use eq instead.

```
$('#mylink').eq(0).click();
```

Comment: This returns the same error as just calling .click(). I think the reason .get(0) works IS because it is returning the DOM element which appears to have a click method in IE6 but not in FF. I guess this narrows the issue to why the DOM element is found but jQuery can't 'click' it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger) ?

```
$("#mylink").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#mylink').trigger('click');
```

*Should* be the same as your first example, though... Do some alerts in IE to make sure the element exists and all that (maybe you have a duplicated ID somewhere or something?).

Comment: Yes, I tried trigger also but it does the same thing as .click()

Answer (score 0):

The *object required* is likely generated because IE can't find the `#mylink` selector in time. Make sure you do the call in the success callback function or provide a timeout function that checks if the element is available before triggering the click:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($("#mylink").length) {
        $("#mylink").trigger('click');
        return false;
    }
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1);
},1);
```

Comment: That's what I thought also but placing it in a timer didn't change anything, even if I set it out 5 seconds.

Comment: @ongle: what does alert($("#mylink").length) tell you?

Comment: @David, The length is 1. As near as I can tell the selector returns a valid jQuery object.